# Creating a smaller list from an existing list

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have a list which goes like this:

```
>>> list1 = ['Mary','had','a','little','lamb','which','was','very','naughty']
```

I had a requirement to create another list(`list2`) out of `list1` which is created by iterating over `list1` and finding the element **little** and then appending **little** and every element that follows **little** to `list2`.

Did a bit a reading up and found that dropwhile from itertools was just made for my requirement.

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> list2 = list(dropwhile(lambda l: 'little' not in l, list1))
>>> list2
['little', 'lamb', 'which', 'was', 'very', 'naughty']
```

Works exactly as I want it.

However,now I have a requirement to specify the ending element as well.So I want a list of elements from **little** to **very** both inclusive as follows:

```
>>>list3
['little', 'lamb', 'which', 'was', 'very']
```

How do I do that with a similar approach?

Comment: You should seriously define border line conditions, because you are getting answers that will blow up on few occasions. Is the presence of elements always guaranteed? Do they occur only single time each? What should happen if not. Is the order guaranteed? What should happen if `very` is before `naughty`...

Comment: @luk32 ...i understand your concerns but i have taken care of these border line conditions..my intention was to get the logic when all these border line conditions are taken care of..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to continue working with `itertools` (not caring about performance):

```
from itertools import dropwhile
list1 = ['Mary','had','a','little','lamb','which','was','very','naughty']

list2 = list(dropwhile(lambda x: x!="little", list1))
list3 = list(dropwhile(lambda x: x!="very", reversed(list2)))
print list(reversed(list3))
```

output:

```
['little', 'lamb', 'which', 'was', 'very']
```

If you care about performance, you should define a custom logic (thanks to @Kasra):

```
list1 = ['Mary','had','a','little','lamb','which','was','very','naughty']

def drop(sequence,start,end):
    keep = False
    for item in sequence:
        if item == start:
            keep = True
        if keep and item == end:
            yield item
            break
        if keep:
            yield item

list3 = drop(list1, 'little', 'very')

print list(list3)
```

Comment: just to understand..what is the problem with performance here..? is the overhead of reversing the list and again reversing it back ?

Comment: Yes, each `list` and `reverse` perform a full scan of the list

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom function,to return a generator :

```
def drop(iterable,start,end):

    for i,x in enumerate(iterable):
        if x==start :
            for y in iterable[i:]:
                if y!=end:
                    yield y
                else:
                    yield end
                    break
```

Demo :

```
list1 = ['Mary','had','a','little','lamb','which','was','very','naughty']
print list(drop(list1,'little','very'))
['little', 'lamb', 'which', 'was', 'very']
```

*Note* that this solution is faster than using `list.index` as its order is O(n) and you use it 2 time, but for preceding function you are iterating over all of your list 1 time in addition one indexing in `iterable[i:]`,that its order is less than O(n),so its faster.

For better understanding look at the following bench-marking :

```
from timeit import timeit

s1="""
list1 = ['Mary','had','a','little','lamb','which','was','very','naughty']
list1[list1.index("little"):list1.index("very")+1]
"""
s2="""
def drop(iterable,start,end):

    for i,x in enumerate(iterable):
        if x==start :
            for y in iterable[i:]:
                if y!=end:
                    yield y
                else:
                    yield end
                    break
list1 = ['Mary','had','a','little','lamb','which','was','very','naughty']
drop(list1,'little','very')
    """


print ' first: ' ,timeit(stmt=s1, number=1000000)
print 'second : ',timeit(stmt=s2, number=1000000)
```

result:

```
 first:  5.87736296654
second :  5.01044201851
```

Comment: Plus 1...Always great when the performance of non pythonic solutions is explored

Comment: just to understand..what does order of O(n) mean ?

Comment: @Amistad In mathematics, big O notation describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity readmore( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing this without using itertools may look some thing like:

```
start = list1.index("little")
end = list1.index("very")
list3 = list1[start:end+1]
```

or simply you can write it as :

```
list3 = list1[list1.index("little"):list1.index("very")+1]
```

Comment: This fails when `very` appears before `little` as well.

Comment: To handle that pass `start` as second argument to `end = list1.index("very")`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
 list1[list1.index('little'):-list1[::-1].index('very')]
```

Result:

```
['little', 'lamb', 'which', 'was', 'very']
```

We search for the second keyword in the reversed list and then use the negative index in the original list.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that does not assume that "little" is before "very":

```
def list_range(ls, a, b):
    a_i, b_i = ls.index(a), ls.index(b)
    if a_i < b_i:
        return ls[a_i:b_i+1]
    else:
        return ls[a_i:b_i-1:-1]

list1 = ['Mary','had','a','little','lamb','which','was','very','naughty']
print list_range(list1, 'little', 'very')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do list slicing.

```
>>> list1 = ['Mary','had','a','little','lamb','which','was','very','naughty']
>>> list1[list1.index('little'):list1.index('very')+1]
['little', 'lamb', 'which', 'was', 'very']
```